# Is there any VPN with API support

Tags: api, vpn

I am looking for a VPN (free or paid) which provides API support along with it so that I can integrate into my application with ease. I've used many VPN's like Cyber Ghost (rumors came that CyberGhost is providing API but I found it is no longer supported) so I am looking for another one. It is for web-scrapping purpose nothing more.

For free public networks I can find http://gimmeproxy.com/ but I prefer virtual private networks since public is slower

Please post any suggestions.

Comment: Check this out, [PureVPN](https://www.purevpn.com/purevpn-api.php).Though never tried it my self but looks promising.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/best-vpn-solution-for-multi-user-api